# SQLite Inner Join Issue

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable

I have two tables with some odd join behavior.  Here is a brief schema with data:

```
CREATE TABLE object(vnum INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE object_affect(vnum INTEGER, apply_id INTEGER, modifier INTEGER);

object
vnum     name
10404    Test Item

object_affect
vnum     apply_id    modifier
10404    1           4
10404    5           2
10404    12          6
```

If I run the below query I should have 3 rows returned however it only returns 1 row.

```
select * from object o
    inner join object_affect oa on oa.vnum = o.vnum 
    where o.vnum = 10404
```

If I change the query to this (change * to oa.vnum).. it return 3 rows:

```
select oa.vnum from object o
    inner join object_affect oa on oa.vnum = o.vnum 
    where o.vnum = 10404
```

Also, if I remove the "PRIMARY KEY" flag in the create table statement from the vnum field on object table the first query that only returned one 1 returns all 3 joined rows correctly.

What am I missing that causes the first query to not return 3 rows of joined data?

Comment: I get 3 records from both queries, at least in MySQL ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74a5dc/2)).

Comment: Which record is being returned?

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/74a5dc/1). Are you using the latest SQLite version?

Comment: The database is created with sqlite 3 from a C program.  The data is being queried via the SQLite ADO.Net provider.  I would expect to see three rows returned (the one row from the left table joined with the 3 rows from the right).  Also not sure why just removing the primary key off of vnum makes the results of the query change.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It returns the 1 record from the object table and then the third record from the object_affect table (1404, 12, 6 - if I remove the primary key attribute, it returns all three, if I select only records from the right table it returns all three).

Comment: This is a truly bizarre thing you have here.  If I were you, I would just use the join version which gives you what you would expect.  Maybe someone else will be able to crack this problem (I can't because I cannot reproduce it).

Comment: I agree.  Being that you verified it's not the query, I opened it up and ran it in a editor that uses a different driver and the same query worked.  I guess I need to figure out why the ADO.Net provider is behaving differently with the same SQL.

Comment: It seems to be an issue in the .net System.Data.DataTable and not sqlite.  If I run that query into a SqliteDataReader it returns 3 rows.  If I load that DataReader (that has 3 rows) into a DataTable it only loads 1 row.

Comment: I believe I have found it.  The display loaded the DataReader into a DataTable which was bound to a DataGridView for display on the form.  I believe the DataTable inferred the primary key from the object table and then could not load the additional rows from the join (didn't report any exceptions though).  That is the choke point (it was not sqlite or the provider for it).  If the primary key attribute is removed from the table it works which supports this theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this again 3.5 years later.  I wanted to share the solution.  The idea in this case is that the DataTable is used to display the results of a query on some kind of control, a DataGrid, etc.  As a result, it doesn't need the constraints the DataTable tries to infer from the database about unique keys, etc.  There's no good way to disable the constraints on the DataTable that I've found by itself but you can couple it with a DataSet and do just that.  This snippet (assuming the SqliteCommand is already setup) works:

```
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    using (var ds = new DataSet() { EnforceConstraints = false })
    {
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        dt.BeginLoadData();
        dt.Load(dr);
        dt.EndLoadData();
        ds.Tables.Remove(dt);
    }
}
```

Basically we temporarly use the DataSet and then discard it (it is important to remove it from the DataSet so the DataSet can Dispose and be garbage collected).  Then you can keep the DataTable and persist it to bind it to a control.